# How to fire checkbox checked event when column binding is done in code behind?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, checkbox, celltemplate

I have a data grid, where I create columns on the fly in the code behind. As I create the column, I create associated cell template and cell edit template to convert the value to boolean to represent the data in check box. All works well. What I would like to do is fire check event with commands. I was able to achieve this in XAML with the following link with doing anything on code behind

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/199477/466179.aspx

I moved the working XAML code to code behind the commands are not firing.

When I have the code in XAML and put a break point in the static resource class, I can see break points are hit. But when I put the same code in code behind the break points are not hit. I thought when we do apply template, the static resources are resolved. It looks like it is not.

For now, I able to catch what is changing by listening to back end data. I would like achieve this with commanding.

Any comments or suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just bind a property to the check box's IsChecked property. And in the setter of the new propery you can call or execute what ever method you are currently executing with the commands.
Will result in less messy XAML

Comment: Thanks and yes that is what I am doing now to resolve the problem. I am more interested in why commands can not be fired when you generate column in code behind.